# How to Sum Two Hex Numbers in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, hex

I am trying to sum two hex numbers in Assembly x8086, each one with one digit. I know how to sum decimals. Can someone show me how to do that? Here is my code:

```
    ADD CL, BL    ; CL and BL have the one digit numbers
    MOV AL, CL  
    MOV AH, 0   
    AAA     
    ADD AX, 3030H   

    MOV BX, AX      
    mov dl, bh      
    call mostrarchar
    mov dl, bl      
    call mostrarchar
    int 20H

Nomeprog ENDP

mostrarchar proc near
 mov AH, 02h
 int 21h
 ret
mostrarchar endp
```

Comment: registers hold bits, base 2. hex is base 16 which translates directly base 10 doesnt translate at all, the assembler has to convert it to binary for you.  Just like if you use a hex number it will translate it for you.   You know how to do one you know how to do the other.

Comment: Do you actually wrote that code?

Comment: If I have a number in BCD or Binary, how do i show it in hex?

Comment: Numbers have no base, [numerals have](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/numbers-numerals-digits.html). Use the ASCII table to convert *hex numeral <-> number*, specifically, the digits 0-9 are identical to decimal, for *a*-*f* you need to add a different offset (no more 30h). Also, be sure to use [comment replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) or your cries will be in vain.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Margaret Bloom, you need your proc `mostrarchar` to detect when the number is less or equal to 9 (it's a digit) and when the number is greater than 9 (it's a letter, 10..15 = 'A'..'F'), example :

```
  mov  dl, 8    
  call mostrarchar  ;DISPLAY '8'.

  mov  dl, 15
  call mostrarchar  ;DISPLAY 'F'.

mostrarchar proc
  cmp  dl, 9
  jbe  digit    ;IF ( DL <= 9 )
;IT'S A LETTER (10..15 = 'A'..'F').
  add  dl, 37h  ;DL+55.    
  jmp  display  ;SKIP "DIGIT:".
digit:  
  add  dl, 30h  ;DL+48.
display:
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h  
  ret
mostrarchar endp
```

Previous code works for one digit only. For bigger numbers, you will need to divide the number by the base (in your case, base 16) several times until it becomes zero, each remainder is one digit, then you call `mostrarchar` to display each hex digit, example:

```
  mov  ax, 15729
  call mostrarnum  ;DISPLAY '3D71'.

mostrarnum proc
;CONVERT NUMBER TO HEX.
  mov  bp, 16      ;BASE.
  mov  cx, 0       ;REMAINDERS COUNTER.
divisions:                 
  mov  dx, 0
  div  bp          ;DX:AX ÷ 16.
  push dx          ;PUSH REMAINDER.
  inc  cx          ;COUNT REMAINDER.
  cmp  ax, 0       
  jne  divisions   ;IF ( AX != 0 )

;DISPLAY HEX DIGITS EXTRACTED FROM NUM.  
remainders:      
  pop  dx
  call mostrarchar ;DISPLAY HEX CHAR.
  loop remainders  ;CX-1. IF ( CX > 0 ) REPEAT.
  ret
mostrarnum endp
```

Proc `mostrarnum` first converts the number into hex by extracting digits with succesive divisions. This digits are stored in stack with `push`. Finally, the digits are retrieved from stack and displayed. This is necessary because the divisions generate the digits in reverse order, by pushing the digits in stack they are reversed again, so, when they come out, they are in normal order.

The addition of numbers don't care about the base (binary, decimal, hex, etc.), numbers, as dwelch said, are just bits, it's you, as human being, who decides if those bits are hex or decimal, etc. Examples :

```
mov  al, 9         ;DECIMAL.
mov  ch, 0Ah       ;10
add  ch, al        ;0Ah + 9 = 13h (19)

mov  dl, 01110011b ;BINARY (115, 73h)
add  ch, dl        ;13h + 115 = 134 (86h)
```

You can display the final result as decimal ("134"), hex ("86") or any other.

By the way, you can use the same technique (succesive divisions by a given base) to convert to any base, for example, dividing by 8 will give you octal, and dividing by 14 will give you ... base 14.